# list sorting task

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I am trying to understand how to sort by multiple columns in Mathematica.

Here is a simple data set consisting of results of sports matches.  Each element represents a game, and contains fields for date, first team's name, first team's score, second team's name, second team's score, and game location (home, away, or neutral).  Some elements may be duplicates, or they may disagree on who played whom, or where a game was played.  (Assumeing one team could only play one game per day.)

I would like to be able to evaluate each game and flag each having a conflict as "FALSE" or not having a conflict as "TRUE".

The score list is called gameList:

```
{{DateObject[{2020,1,1}],"Alpha",1,"Bravo",2,"away"},
 {DateObject[{2020,1,1}],"Bravo",2,"Alpha",1,"neutral"},
 {DateObject[{2020,1,1}],"Charlie",3,"Delta",4,"home"},
 {DateObject[{2020,1,1}],"Delta",4,"Charlie",3,"away"},
 {DateObject[{2020,1,2}],"Echo",5,"Foxtrot",6,"home"},
 {DateObject[{2020,1,2}],"Foxtrot",5,"Echo",6,"away"},
 {DateObject[{2020,1,2}],"Gulf",7,"Hotel",10,"home"},
 {DateObject[{2020,1,3}],"India",9,"Juliet",2,"home"},
 {DateObject[{2020,1,3}],"Kilo",10,"India",9,"away"},
 {DateObject[{2020,1,3}],"Lima",11,"Mike",12,"neutral"}}
```

Here is some code that flips (if necessary) team and score pairs so that the team whose name starts earlier in the alphabet comes first in each game record.  In the event the names and scores are reordered, the game location is also changed from home to away or vice versa.

```
alphaSortKey = 
  Table[AlphabeticOrder[gameList[[i, 2]], gameList[[i, 4]]], {i, 
    Length[gameList]}];
gameList = 
  Table[Append[gameList[[i]], alphaSortKey[[i]]], {i, 
    Length[gameList]}];

regular = Cases[gameList, {_, _, _, _, _, _, 1}];
regular = Table[Take[regular[[i]], 6], {i, Length[regular]}];

needTeamsFlip = Cases[gameList, {_, _, _, _, _, _, -1}];
holderLoca = Table[needTeamsFlip[[i, 6]], {i, Length[needTeamsFlip]}];
holderLoca = 
  Table[If[holderLoca[[i]] == "home", holderLoca[[i]] = "away", 
    If[holderLoca[[i]] == "away", holderLoca[[i]] = "home", 
     holderLoca[[i]] = "neutral"]], {i, Length[needTeamsFlip]}];
needTeamsFlip = 
  Table[Take[needTeamsFlip[[i]], 5], {i, Length[needTeamsFlip]}];
needTeamsFlip = 
  Table[Append[needTeamsFlip[[i]], holderLoca[[i]]], {i, 
    Length[needTeamsFlip]}];
holderTeam = Table[needTeamsFlip[[i, 2]], {i, Length[needTeamsFlip]}];
holderScor = Table[needTeamsFlip[[i, 3]], {i, Length[needTeamsFlip]}];
Table[needTeamsFlip[[i, 3]] = needTeamsFlip[[i, 5]], {i, 
   Length[needTeamsFlip]}];
Table[needTeamsFlip[[i, 2]] = needTeamsFlip[[i, 4]], {i, 
   Length[needTeamsFlip]}];
Table[needTeamsFlip[[i, 4]] = holderTeam[[i]], {i, 
   Length[needTeamsFlip]}];
Table[needTeamsFlip[[i, 5]] = holderScor[[i]], {i, 
   Length[needTeamsFlip]}];
needTeamsFlip = 
  Table[Take[needTeamsFlip[[i]], 6], {i, Length[needTeamsFlip]}];


ordered = 
  DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Join[{needTeamsFlip}, {regular}], 1]];
Column[ordered = SortBy[ordered, {#[[1]] &, #[[2]] &}]]

ordered = 
  DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Join[{needTeamsFlip}, {regular}], 1]];
```

But

```
 SortBy[ordered, {#[[1]] &, #[[2]] &, #[[4]] &}]
```

returns an error.

The desired output would be:

```
{{DateObject[{2020,1,1}],"Alpha",1,"Bravo",2,"neutral",FALSE},
{DateObject[{2020,1,1}],"Alpha",1,"Bravo",2,"away",FALSE},
{DateObject[{2020,1,1}],"Charlie",3,"Delta",4,"home",TRUE},
{DateObject[{2020,1,2}],"Echo",6,"Foxtrot",5,"home",FALSE},
{DateObject[{2020,1,2}],"Echo",5,"Foxtrot",6,"home",FALSE},
{DateObject[{2020,1,2}],"Gulf",7,"Hotel",8,"home",TRUE},
{DateObject[{2020,1,3}],"India",9,"Kilo",10,"home",FALSE},
{DateObject[{2020,1,3}],"India",9,"Juliet",10,"home",FALSE},
{DateObject[{2020,1,3}],"Lima",11,"Mike",12,"neutral",TRUE}}
```

Thanks in advance for suggestions!

Comment: the dates in `gameList`  need to be edited (they do not match the dates in desired output).

Comment: Thanks for catching that.  Fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sorted = gameList;
orderings = Ordering /@ gameList[[All, {2, 4}]];
sorted[[All, {2, 4}]] = Sort /@ sorted[[All, {2, 4}]];
sorted[[All, {3, 5}]] = MapThread[#[[#2]] &, {sorted[[All, {3, 5}]], orderings}];
sorted[[All, 6]] = MapThread[If[#2 == {1, 2}, #, # /. {"home" -> "away", 
       "away" -> "home"}] &, {sorted[[All, 6]], orderings}];
sorted = DeleteDuplicates@sorted;

dateteamcounts = Counts[Join @@ (sorted[[All, {1, #}]] & /@ {2, 4})]; 

desired = Join[sorted, 
    {Max[dateteamcounts /@ {#[[{1, 2}]], #[[{1, 4}]]}] == 1} & /@ sorted, 2];

Grid[desired, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

#### Update:

An alternative approach:

```
ClearAll[sORT, dESIRED]
sORT = DeleteDuplicates[# /. {a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_} /; OrderedQ[{d, b}] :>
   {a, d, e, b, c, f /. {"home" -> "away", "away" -> "home"}}] &; 

dESIRED = Module[{s = sORT @ #,  k = Function[x, x[[{1, #}]] & /@ {2, 4}]},
   Join[s, {Max[Counts[Join @@ k /@ s] /@ k[#]] == 1} & /@ s, 2]] &;

dESIRED @ gameList == desired
```

> True

Comment: Thanks @kglr for the succinct improvement in code!  Still would like the last field indicating conflict/no conflict with the other elements...

Comment: @Suite401, please see the update.

Comment: many runes to chew on :)  Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: is there a way to use IgnoreCase in either solution?  They undesireably invert the positions of teams whose names begin with two capital letters, e.g.

Comment: {1-Jan,AB,1,Ac,2,AWAY} into {1-Jan,Ac,2,AB,1,AWAY}.  ascii numbers for caps are different from lower cases...thoughts?

Comment: @Suite401, in the first method, maybe you can use `orderings = Ordering /@ ToUpperCase[gameList[[All, {2, 4}]]];
sorted[[All, {2, 4}]] = SortBy[ToUpperCase] /@ sorted[[All, {2, 4}]];` and change the string replacement rule to `{"home" | "HOME" -> "away", "away" | "AWAY" -> "home"}`? In the second method change `OrderedQ[{d, b}]` to `OrderedQ[ToTupperCase@{d, b}]`.

Comment: Preliminary tests on the revision for the first method are favorable.  Thank you so much for your time with this!  Will work on the revision for the second method.